# Mergesort program stuck in error

Tags: c++, c, arrays, sorting, mergesort

Please help me to <s>guess</s> understand the mistake in the following code.
It's returning the same array.

e.g if I give it 2, 5, 3, 1 as input, it returns 2, 5, 3, 1 without sorting.

Example output:

```
Enter the total number of elements: 4
Enter the elements which to be sort: 
2
5
3
1 
Un-Sorted Array: 2531
Sorted Array: 2531
```

This is my code — what's going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int l,m,h;

int merge(int A[], int low, int mid, int high){

    int A1[10];
    int A2[10];
    int n1, n2, i, j, k;

    n1=m-l+1;
    n2=h-m;

    for (i=0; i<n1; i++)
        A1[i]=A[l+i];

    for (j=0; j<n2; j++)
        A1[j]=A[m+j+1];


     A1[i]=9999;
     A2[i]=9999;

     i=0;
     j=0;
     for(k=1; k<=h; k++){
        if (A1[i] <= A2[j])
            A[k]=A1[i++];
        else
            A[k]=A2[j++];
     }
     return 0;

 }

int merge_sort(int A[],int low,int high){

    int mid;

    if(low<high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        merge_sort(A,low,mid);
        merge_sort(A,mid+1,high);
        merge(A,low,mid,high);
    }
    return 0;
 }

 int A[20];

 int main(){

     int  i,n;

     cout << "Enter the total number of elements: ";
     cin >> n;

     cout << "\nEnter the elements which to be sort: ";

     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         cin >> A[i];
     }

     cout << " \nUn-Sorted Array: ";

     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         cout << A[i];
     }

     merge_sort(A,0,n-1);

     cout << "\nSorted Array: ";

     for(i=0;i<n;i++){
         cout << A[i];

     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why *guess* the mistake (or ask strangers to guess on your behalf)? Use a debugger and find out for sure! You might even learn something useful in the process.

Comment: Marked as off-topic because is asking "what's going wrong?" without any sign of effort in searching for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int merge(int A[], int low, int mid, int high){

    int A1[10];
    int A2[10];
    int n1, n2, i, j, k;

    n1=mid-low+1;//use parameter
    n2=high-mid;//ditto

    for (i=0; i<n1; i++)
        A1[i]=A[low+i];//ditto

    for (j=0; j<n2; j++)
        A2[j]=A[mid+j+1];//ditto


     A1[i]=9999;
     A2[j]=9999;//typo i -> j

     i=0;
     j=0;
     for(k=low; k<=high; k++){//k=1 typo and use parameter
        if (A1[i] <= A2[j])
            A[k]=A1[i++];
        else
            A[k]=A2[j++];
     }
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: BLUEPIXY if i do this then it gives absurd results or garbage value as under Un-Sorted Array: 2531
Sorted Array: 2-1217837648-10742105761

Comment: @user3500553 see [DEMO](http://ideone.com/lt6QAr)

Answer (score 0):

Your `merge` function ignores its parameters `low`, `mid`, `high` and uses the global variables `l`, `h`, `m` which are set to zero when the program starts and never set non-zero.  Thus, it sorts (or might conceivably sort) an empty array and leaves the rest of the data unsorted.  (Just one more reason to distrust global variables.)

I've not verified whether there are other problems (there probably are).  But starting by paying attention to your function parameters would help.

If your compiler was not warning you about unused parameters, you either haven't got your warnings turned up high enough or you need a better compiler.